# Which ciphers and modes does SQLCipher offers?

Tags: sql, cryptography, sqlcipher

In SQLCipher I can change the cipher using `PRAGMA cipher`. The default cipher is AES-256-cbc. What are the supported ciphers and modes of operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLCipher uses OpenSSL, and thus relies on the underlying cipher suite supported by the library, initialized using the standard cipher-length-mode identifier. However, this feature is mainly reserved for specific circumstances where an alternate cipher is required. We generally recommend that integrations use the default aes-256-cbc.